# Frigidaire affinity washer won't fill

Tags: washing-machine

I have a Frigidaire washing machine that at first would not dispense water during the rinse cycle.

I ignored that because it only happened on certain settings.

Now, the washer won't fill with water. I have done my research and I know about cleaning the screens at the intake valve. Water then travels up to the pressure switch.

I can hear the pressure switch click but have not tested it with a multimeter.

If it clicks does that automatically mean it is good and I don't need to test it?

I would think that it is not the intake valve because it only wouldn't fill on the rinse cycle before.

I have never done this before and before I check this one with a multimeter and order parts, I want to know that it will work if I do so I am not wasting time and energy and just end up frustrated.
Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Including a model number and link to the documentation would help us help you. Also, is this a dish or clothes washer? Not sure how much difference it will make, but it would be good to know.